# uses of with, at, of

Tags: grammar, expressions

I  would like to now if I am using the prepositions correctly:

"She was not pleased **with** her job and was tired **of** doing the same thing every day, but everybody was surprised **at** her attitude"

I always confuse them.

Comment: I am sure about the tired of. Tired of is correctly used here.

Comment: It is the sort of thing you can easily verify on your own when you have access to a computer. [Pleased with](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pleased+with). [Tired of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Tired+of). [Surprised at](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/surprised?q=surprised). "Surprised" can be followed by different prepositions but your sentence is perfectly correct.

Comment: Correct: "think" to "thing"

Answer (score 3):

"Pleased with" and "tired of" are unambiguously correct.

"Surprised at" is also correct, but in American English it sounds a little clunky. In a sentence like yours above, I would usually choose "by": "...but everybody was surprised by her attitude."

One weird quirk with the word "surprised" is the change in meaning when the object of the preposition is a person. Consider:

> Julie was surprised by Samantha.

This indicates that Samantha surprised Julie on purpose somehow, like by hiding behind the curtains for a surprise party, or sending her an unexpected gift.

> Julie was surprised at Samantha.

This indicates that Samantha behaved in a way that Julie hadn't anticipated. Samantha wasn't behaving with Julie in mind; she just acted, but her behavior surprised Julie.

That is just a weird distinction with people, though. For the most part, you can use "at" and "by" interchangeably with "surprised" and people will get your meaning without much trouble.

Comment: They have a kind of from/to, **by/at**, yin/yang relation, though not to be taken absolutely so.  Yin: "I was warmed by her kind words."  Yang: "I was angry at her." and "She threw the ball at Julie."  So **"surprised by"** has a kind of receiving connotation while **"surprised at"** has a kind of sharper, outwardly directed connotation.