# Should I use "of" or "with" in "tired {of/with} homework" or "afraid {of/with} the dark"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

I am tired **of** homework.
I am tired **with** homework.

I am afraid **of** the dark.
I am afraid **with**the dark.
Is there any difference in case of usage?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/16853/, http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4553/

Comment: *I'm tired **of** weightlifting* = *Weightlifting now bores me*. *I'm tired **with** weightlifting* = *The reason I'm physically fatigued is because I've been lifting weights*. But that second sense would more often be expressed with ***from, through,*** or ***because of***. And *I am afraid **with** the dark* is extremely unlikely if not idiomatically invalid in *any* context.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers "I’m dying of thirst" = thrist kills me. 
I’m dying with thirst= I'm dying because there is no water.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers What about these two : I'm short of money and I'm short in money

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each of the cases listed "of" would be used instead of "with".

> I am afraid of the dark.
>
> I am tired of homework.

Some examples of "with" would be:

> I am busy with my homework.
>
> I met a girl with blonde hair.
>
> Will you come with me?
>
> I eat soup with a spoon.

As a student of other languages, I can easily see why this is so confusing, but it is not so much an issue of the rules grammar as it is an issue of definition of words.  The word "of" has a myriad of meanings as is the case with several prepositions. They are connecting words. As such, they are highly adaptable.
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of

Comment: Your examples are correct, but you don't explain why "of" should be used instead of "with". 'I'm bored with homework' or 'I'm bored of homework' - how do I use your answer to figure out which one is correct? Why "busy with" but "tired of"?

Comment: @ColleenV, adjective + preposition combinations (like *afraid of*) and verb + preposition combinations (like *eat with*) are common in English, but unfortunately there is no real system to *which* preposition goes with which adjective/verb. You can find lists of common combinations if you google, but you basically just need to memorize them.

Comment: @nedibes That's right - and that information should be in an answer if it is to be complete.